# How to auto inc the the primary key of a table in Oracle from Java code via JPA-Hibernate?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

Im using Java code (JPA2 with Hibernate 4.1) to insert into Oracle db 12c.

Table : Dept :
Name   Null     Type

---

DEPTNO NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
DNAME           VARCHAR2(14) 
LOC             VARCHAR2(13)

From Java code, I am inserting value for DNAME and LOC as 'Research','London'.
Entity class :

```
@Entity(name="Department")
@Table(name="mydept")
public class Department {
    @Id 
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MYDEPT_SEQ", sequenceName ="MYDEPT_SEQ", allocationSize = 10, initialValue = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MYDEPT_SEQ")
    @Column(name="deptno")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="dname")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="loc")
    private String location;
```

MYDEPT_SEQ :
create sequence mydept_seq;
So it takes the default values like MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1.

The id generated from Java is random and takes even -ve values.
But shouldn't these values be overriden by the properties specified for @SequenceGenerator in the java entity class?

Not using hibernate.cfg, but Annotations as shown in the Entity class above.

persistence.xml :

```
<!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="1"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
```

How do I make the code adhere to allocationSize = 10, initialValue = 50, ie, insert deptno as 50,60,70.....

Comment: <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" removed the negative values. Now I have allocationSize = 10, initialValue = 50 in @SequenceGenerator of Entity class. DB sequence is created start with 50 increment by 10. But ids are gen like 500,600,800. Any solution for creating ids like 50,60,70..?

Comment: Solution : DB sequence - increment by 1 start with 5; allocationSize = 10, in @SequenceGenerator of Entity class. So now getting ids like 50,60,70.But allocationSize=10 means dbseq.nextval will be called from db after the 10th insert. But in my case, it is being called everytime. Any answers for that?

Comment: allocation size of 10 means it allocates 10 ids ... for that EntityManager typically. If you then close the EntityManager then any unused ids are thrown away. Depends how many inserts you have in one EntityManager usage, and you present no persistence code